# Setting Singleton Property as False for MethodInvokingFactoryBean in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, javabeans, spring-bean

I have a prototype bean 'client' for which I want to call a method 'addHandler' every time it is instantiated. I am using 'MethodInvokingFactoryBean' for this. I the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingFactoryBean.html), I can see that by default MethodInvokingFactoryBean operates in a singleton fashion and caches the result of 'getObject' to return in subsequent calls.

To circumvent this, I want to call 'setSingleton' with 'false'. I am not sure about how to do this.

```
    <bean id="provider" class="com.example.credProvider">
        <constructor-arg value="key1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="handler" class="com.example.Handler"/>

    <bean id="client" class="com.example.DBClient" scope="prototype">
        <constructor-arg><ref local="provider"/></constructor-arg>
        <property name="endpoint" value="http://xyz:8080/" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject"><ref local="client"/></property>
        <property name="targetMethod"><value>addHandler</value></property>
        <property name="arguments">
            <ref local="handler" />
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Will adding a scope="prototype" like this help? -

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean" scope="prototype">
...
</bean>
```

Comment: do you have the access to source code for `com.example.DBClient` ? if yes you could introduce an additional constructor which takes provider and handler as arguments! In case no, you could consider extending it (if not final)

Comment: did a quick check with [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.1.1.RELEASE/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java#MethodInvokingFactoryBean) you can set the flag as `false` as `<property name="singleton"><value>false</value></property>` within the bean definition of `MethodInvokingFactoryBean`

Comment: No, I do not have the access to the DBClient source code. I have tried setting the singleton property, the problem with this is, the first instance of the client is called by MentodInvokingFactoryBean but the subsequent ones are not being invoked. I suspect the cause of this is, as the method does not return a value, that value is not being referenced anywhere. So, spring is not calling factory-bean at all later.

Comment: Why not simply create a factory to construct the `DBClient` a lot easier and clearer than trying to hide this in xml configuration.